# Homework - problem calculating the cost of purchases

Tags: c++

I'm currently in a Beginning Programming C++ class. I'm having trouble with my current assignment that is asking me to write a program that asks the user for the number of units sold, validate the number of units, and compute the total cost of purchase. I'm also needing to format the output to display to match the output given.

Any input from the units assumes it's receiving a 50% discount. Where am I messing up here?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//Declare variables
    int units, amount_no_discount;
    const double PRICE_OF_PACKAGE = 99.95;
    double discountAmt, discount, netPrice;

//Ask user to enter the amount of units sold
    cout << "Enter the units sold: ";
    cin >> units;

    
    
    if (units <= 0)                 // Validate
    {
        cout << "This is an invalid number of units. Units sold must be 1 or more.";
    }
    else
    {
        if (units <= 9)
        {
            discount = .00;         // 0% discount
        }
        else if (units <= 19)
        {
            discount = .20;         // 20% discount
        }
        else if (units <= 49)
        {
            discount = .30;         // 30% discount 
        }
        else if (units <= 99)
        {
            discount = .40;         // 40% discount 
        }
        else (units >= 100);
        {
            discount = .50;         // 50% discount 
        }

    }
    
    //Calculations

    discountAmt = (units * PRICE_OF_PACKAGE) * discount;
    amount_no_discount = units * PRICE_OF_PACKAGE;
    netPrice = (units * PRICE_OF_PACKAGE) - discountAmt;
    
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << right;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Software Sales:\n";
    cout << "Regular Price of " <<  setw(3) << units << ":" << setprecision(2) << setw(10) << amount_no_discount << endl;
    cout << "Discounted  " << discount << "%:" << setw(16) << discountAmt << endl;
    cout << "Net Price: " << right << setw(23) << netPrice << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Recommendation: Provide the input you are using, the output you get, and the output you want to get. Also one of the best tools you'll ever find is the debugger. With a debugger you can "step" through your program one line at a time and watch what happens as it happens. If you keep a close eye out for when the program does something unexpected, like storing the wrong  value or taking the wrong branch, you'll find bugs quickly and either be able to solve your own problems or be able to make really focused questions that are answered in minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo when determining the amount of `discount`.  If the `units` entered is `>= 100`, you reach this statement:

```cpp
else (units >= 100); // <-- typos here!
{
    discount = .50;         // 50% discount 
}
```

The code is *syntactically correct* but *logically wrong*. It does not do what you are expecting, the flow ends up being interpreted by the compiler as doing this instead:

```cpp
if (units <= 9)
{
    discount = .00;         // 0% discount
}
else if (units <= 19)
{
    discount = .20;         // 20% discount
}
else if (units <= 49)
{
    discount = .30;         // 30% discount 
}
else if (units <= 99)
{
    discount = .40;         // 40% discount 
}
else
    (units >= 100);         // <-- no-op!

discount = .50;         // 50% discount
```

So, the `discount` always ends up being `.50` regardless of the `units` actually entered.

You need to change the final `else` statement to this instead:

```cpp
else if (units >= 100)
{
    discount = .50;         // 50% discount 
}
```

Or this, since you already know the `units` must be >= 100 by that point, so it is not worth validating again:

```cpp
else
{
    discount = .50;         // 50% discount 
}
```

---

On a side note, if the `units` entered is <= 0, you output an error message, but then you proceed to perform the calculations anyway.  You should add a `return` statement to the failed validation:

```cpp
if (units <= 0)                 // Validate
{
    cout << "This is an invalid number of units. Units sold must be 1 or more.";
    return 0; // <-- add this
}
```